# Why does my python installation recognize /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/?

Tags: python, homebrew

I have installed Python using Homebrew.  I would like for this installation of python to recognize only one site-pakages directory -- `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

However, when I start the python shell and give the command `print [f for f in sys.path if f.endswith('packages')]` I get the following output:

`['/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']`

Why is `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` sitting at the end there?  Shouldn't the Homebrew installation of Python have just one main site-packages directory under /usr/local/ ???

Edit: I am using virtualenv -- but this is occurring after a fresh install of python using homebrew before I have even had a chance to install virtualenv.  Also, I'm interested in why it is happening, not on what I should do to get around it.

Comment: you should consider using virtualenv  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Comment: I am using virtualenv -- this problem was occurring while I was trying to get virtualenv running in the first place.

Comment: create the virtual environment with no site packages: mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.  But I'm interested in why it is happening in the first place.  Let's say I didn't want to use virtual environments -- my homebrew installation of python still shouldn't recognize /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.  I want to know why it does.

Comment: Do you have a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set?

Comment: No.  `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Created a stack overflow account just for this, since I was so annoyed by it.  I actually had a bug inadvertently caused by that extra "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages" in the sys.path

Researching it led me to this:
http://bugs.python.org/issue4865

tl;dr: From what I can tell, they throw that path in there to help people that installed packages for the apple-shipped python, but then later would try to use those packages in other versions of python (like the ones used by homebrew, macports, etc).