# Python packages in wrong location after installing Homebrew Python?

Tags: python, homebrew

After installing Homebrew's Python onto a system with an established Apple Python, the last entries listed by `sys.path` using Homebrew's Python are

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-package
```

This is the reverse of the order I expect. Shouldn't Homebrew's packages be searched first? (In fact, [shouldn't it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13001273/656912) be the *only* place searched?) That's what's [implied in the documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-and-Python.md#site-packages-and-the-pythonpath). Where is it set and how can I (or should I) change it?

Or is this the way Brewed Python is supposed to work? Is it designed to *prevent duplicate packages* and assume that any package in the system `site-packages` is meant to stay there unless explicitly uninstalled and then subsequently installed (into Brew's); with the exception of `pip` and `setuptools` which *are* duplicated (and put first in Brewed Python's path).

Comment: Thanks for this question. I have received dismissive treatment when asking about packages not being found after `pip install` (and even when using the *brew* version).  I am on the verge of dumping `brew` version of python due to their mishandling of package installs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the intended behaviour. The rationale behind it is that you can keep using your old installed modules despite the fact that you are now using a new homebrewed Python.

Now this has some drawbacks, for example some libraries like numpy, won't work across different Python versions, so if you had installed numpy it will be imported from the old system's `site-packages` and won't work.

There are at least two ways to change `sys.path`:

**Use a `.pth` file:**

Python will pick that from some of the builtin locations (ex: ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth). This appends to `sys.path` which is not ideal but has the advantage that it won't be picked by Python 3. It is currently the [recommended method](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27138). You can achieve this with:

```
echo "$(brew --prefix)/lib/python2.7/site-packages" > ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

**Set `PYTHONPATH`:**

This gets prepended to `sys.path`, it has the drawback that is global to all python versions so it is not recommended if you are going to use different python versions. You can do it by adding to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=`brew --prefix`/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

I personally used option 2 with homebrew-python (I now use and recommend Anaconda). My reasons were that I didn't care about system's Python or Python 3 at the time.

Comment: That's not the issue: I've confirmed that it's Brew's Python and Brew's PIP that are running; `/usr/local/bin` is ahead of `/usr/bin` (always has been); the only thing in `PYTHONPATH ` is a directory where I keep some packages I've written (setting it to nothing doesn't change the behavior).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, please try setting the `PYTHONPATH`, I edited my answer.

Comment: That will put the Brew packages on the path for the system's Python as well though, right? And it hardcodes to 2.7.

Comment: That will work; but the question is, Should I do it? Maybe Brew is supposed to work this way — i.e. it *prevents duplicates* and assumes that any package that you have in the system `site-packages` is meant to stay there unless you remove it and then install into Brew's; and only `pip` and `setuptools` are duplicated (and put first in Brewed Python's path).

Comment: You can decide what you want, I for example don't have the system's `site-packages` in my `PYTHONPATH`, to avoid incompatibilities between python versions, I don't use the system's Python anymore, so why would I want to use the old packages? In your case may be you want one or the other to have preference.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I just want to make sure I understand the intended design — and whether what I'm seeing is expected — before I much around; that's the main question. I've expanded the question a bit to focus on that.

Comment: (Not the main question; but how, by they way, would I get the System's `site-packages` *off* of my `PYTHONPATH` — I don't put it there with nothing I know of?)

Comment: Sorry I think this has become a [Chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions),:-). Please make a new question for the intention issue and the PYTHONPATH is easy, just edit the .bash_profile, .bashrc.

Comment: No, the OQ is about "Shouldn't Homebrew's packages be searched first?": whether it's supposed to be that way an whether I should change it. I'll add a new question though about *how* to change it by removing the System's `site-packages` as you suggest.

Comment: (Can't add a question today — hit my limit — in the meantime: a hit about how to remove my system's `site-packages` from the search path that Brew's Python uses to find packages?)

Comment: I answered the first question. I left the second out because I don't have homebrew installed right now. I agree it would belong better in a new question.

Comment: I can see that the presence of both site packages is intended to ensure access to system site packages; but what confuses me is the *order*; is that intended too?

Comment: Yes, that is why they recommend appending instead of prepending. They had extensive discussions about what should be the default behaviour that works best for the majority of users. You shouldn't take their recommendation so seriously and adapt it to your own situation. There is not an ideal solution for all cases.

Comment: Cool. I just wanted to make sure I it wasn't a sign of a messed up configuration. I think your suggestion about entirely removing the system's site packages from my my Brew Python is the way to go; I'll have to wait to ask a new question about that.

Comment: In theory you can leave the old packages, if you have new homebrew versions and `PYTHONPATH` is correctly set these will be picked first. Also consider Anaconda.

Comment: Yes, I'd leave them. I just want to get them out of Brew's sight too. (There's other odd stuff going on too; like I get errors about `The directory '...' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.` using Brew's pip (for anything, even `list`. More questions when I can.)

Comment: Note though that there may be [problems with cutting out the system](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27969359/656912) entirely (though I agree it's a desirable approach).

Comment: Hi! I'm a Homebrew maintainer. It's probably a misfeature that the /Library site-packages is considered before the one in Homebrew's prefix. There's an open issue about changing that here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/28597 and I'll probably spend some time on it soon.