# How do I remove my system's 'site-packages' from the search path for Python packages?

Tags: python, path, package

My search path for Python packages contains an entry for my system's site packages in

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

This has always been there, but now that I have installed Homebrew's Python, it has been suggested that I remove it ([assuming this is safe and makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27952596/656912)) from the package search path for Homebrew's Python. But I'm not sure how (or how it even gets there: I don't add it to `PYTHONPATH`, for example).

How do I remove my system's `site-packages` from the search path that Brew's Python uses for packages?

Comment: What does `echo $PYTHONPATH` from the shell prompt say?

Comment: It just has a directory I add cotainign packages I've developed (e.g. `/pathto/mydevd/pkgs`). I set it in `.bash_profile` with `export PYTHONPATH="/pathto/mydevd/pkgs:${PYTHONPATH}"`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to pass `-S` to `python` on the command line, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-S).

Comment: That will exclude ALL site packages (and only when I can get at the command line) I just want to exclude the *systems* ([I have others, e.g. Homebrew's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27952596/656912)).

Comment: Well, in that case, your per-project virtualenv should be excluding system site-packages by default.  You are using a virtualenv for each project, right?

Comment: Yes, but this is about doing it globally.

Comment: Why does it need to be global?  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Think `--system-site-packages`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that problem.  If you manually grant your virtualenv access to SSP, then it will have access to SSP.  Why is that bad?

Comment: It's about getting it to treat the Homebrew site packages as *the* system site packages. But it's also about cases that don't use virtualenvs (we don't always). Think of it as an attempt to treat Homebrew as the system Python (by excluding entirely the actual system's site packages, which are currently included *ahead* of Homebrew's). See the [referenced question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27952596/656912) and the suggested approach there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68914/discussion-between-kevin-and-raxacoricofallapatorius).