# Can I specify which 'site-packages' directory MySQL Utilities should be installed in?

Tags: python, mysql, homebrew

I have a Homebrew installation of Python that I use as my principal (nearly exclusive) Python and need to install [MySQL Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/). But the installer places the packages in my system's `site-packages` directory rather than Homebrew's.

Is there a way to specify which `site-packages` directory should hold the MySQL Utilities files?

Comment: But you are not using pip either.

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing with `pip`, `pip -t /what/ever thepackage` will install packages in `/what/ever`.  If you're installing with something else, you'd better specify **what** that something else **is**!-)

Comment: I'm installing from the "installer" (DMG) mentioned in the OQ; downloaded from the linked page.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, a typical MacOSX installer will offer the choice to "install somewhere else", but it depends on who wrote the installer in question -- so if that installer doesn't offer this option you'd better get in touch with the installer's author directly.